# How to show Flutter Spinkit when a button is pressed?

Tags: flutter

I have a button that checks for login credentials and if they were correct, navigates the user to another page. I want to use `Flutter Spinkit`. I have the following code for the button:

```
onPressed: () async {
  const SpinKitWave(
    color: Colors.white, type: SpinKitWaveType.start);
  var service = Services();
  var response =
    await service.login(username.text, password.text);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    SharedPreferences prefs =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('myUsername', username.text);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
        const HomePage(),
      ));
  }
},
```

When I press the button, the `Flutter Spinkit` does not show anything.

Comment: Can you please add more details about what doesn't work with Flutter Spinkit?

Comment: @TarHalda I cannot see any spinner.

Comment: What is SpinKitWave? I mean its a widget?

Comment: Some examples are here in `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit` but I cannot use them in my own case.